# If href="#" or target="_blank" then no prevention of <a> request

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, popup, href

So I have this registration site, and clicking ANY link on the page during the registration will prevent the user from exiting the page and a warning window pops up. But I want to exlude `<a>` tags that consist of `href="#"` and `target="_blank"` - so that when a user clicks a link containing one of these mentioned tag elements, the request is accepted and no warning window is opened. How can this be done?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery( function()
        {
            var value = jQuery("a").click( function() 
            {
                answer = confirm("Do you want to exit the registration process?");
                if ( answer )
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: FYI, `var value` will be the jq set of matched elements, not the returned value from click handler

Answer (score 1):

This might help you...

```
jQuery( function()
        {            
            var value = jQuery("a").click( function() 
            {
                if(jQuery(this).attr('target')=='_blank' || jQuery(this).attr('href')=='#')
                    return false;

                answer = confirm("Do you want to exit the registration process?");
                if ( answer )
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }

                return false;

            });
        });
```

Comment: I guess you meant `return true;` not `return false;`

Comment: @A.Wolff `return false` because we have to exlude <a> tags that consist of `href="#"` and `target="_blank"`.

Comment: But OP wants default behaviour and in jQuery, `return false;` is shorthand for `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly.
 I think this is what you need

```
jQuery( function(){

            var value = jQuery("a").click( function(){

                var url = this.href.split('/');
                var isanchor = url[url.length - 1] === '#';
                var isblank = this.target === '_blank';

                if(isanchor || isblank){ //if url === # or target is '_blank'

                    answer = confirm("Do you want to exit the registration process?");
                    if ( answer )
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped with the href="#", although the rest is still a problem. 

When I click an <a> tag with target_blank, the warning popup still appears. And now the normal <a> tags are disabled. For normal <a> tags without href="#" or target_blank I want the popup box to appear when clicking them. 

Is that understandable?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you need, can you explain in steps? ---  "And now the normal <a> tags are disabled. For normal <a> tags without href="#" or target_blank I want the popup box to appear when clicking them." Change `if(isanchor || isblank){` to `if(!isanchor || !isblank){`